# Intellij maven version in terminal is not the right one

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I needed to update my maven version to 3.6.3 (I had 3.3.3 before).

I updated the system variables, the M2_HOME, changed the Path also, modified in intellij from file -> settings, the maven home directory, invalidated caches and restarted, but when I type in the terminal "mvn --version", I get 3.3.3...

If I run install from the maven toolbar, it works ( it sees the right version), but I need to run it from terminal and from there I get an error saying that the version is too old.
What should I do in order to have it updated in the terminal ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `when I type in the terminal "mvn --version", I get 3.3.3...` Do you mean in IDE Terminal? Is it different with the OS terminal? Please follow https://www.baeldung.com/install-maven-on-windows-linux-mac#installing-maven-on-windows After you change Maven in the OS do not forget to restart IDE

Comment: Remote the `M2_HOME` and only add the it to PATH variable. Restart the console of the OS as well as the IDE. Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade to most recent version of Maven 3.6.3 instead of 3.3.3 ?...

Answer (score 0):

Add the maven installation bin path for the newer version (3.6.3 here) to your PATH variable, that resolved the issue for me.

Using the mvn -v command in Terminal displayed the correct version after that:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T20:36:16+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/anbansal/apache-maven-3.6.2
```